# Removing sprite when Touched

Tags: java, libgdx, touch, sprite

The sprite is spawned every second and when it's touched, it should be removed.

This is what I did:

```
//Render the sprites and making them move:
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    for(Sprite drawEnemy:enemies) {
        drawEnemy.draw(batch);
        drawEnemy.translateY(deltaTime * movement);
        touchInput(drawEnemy.getX(),drawEnemy.getY(),
            drawEnemy.getWidth(),drawEnemy.getHeight(),drawEnemy);
    }
}

//Detecting the touch input:
public void touchInput(float x,float y,float w,float h,Sprite sprite){
    float touchX=Gdx.input.getX();
    float touchY=Gdx.input.getY();

    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        if(touchX > x && touchX < x+w ){
            enemyIterator.remove();
            Pools.free(sprite);
        }
    }
}
```

The touch input is detected, but I'm not sure how to remove them.
The result is an error when I touch them.

Comment: What error? ConcurrentModification? If you have an error, it will be good to include the stacktrace.

Comment: Where do you declare `enemyIterator`? This doesn't work because whatever `enemyIterator` references, it's not the same iterator used in your `draw` method because you never got a reference to it. Also, you need to convert touch coordinates to world coordinates using the camera (unproject) before you can test whether it was touched.

Comment: Yes, concurrent modification error. And the iterator is accessible by  all methods, The touch detection works because I first set it to print out something whenever a sprite is touched and it works all the time.

Comment: Well, like I said, you cannot reuse an iterator, so you should not be storing a reference to it to be used by other methods. That's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse an iterator, so your `enemyIterator` is invalid and will cause exceptions.

To avoid needing to do this, change your `touchInput` method to simply test whether the object should be removed, not to remove it. Also note that you need to convert screen coordinates to world coordinates, so you must use the camera as well.

```
private Vector3 TMPVEC = new Vector3();

public boolean touched(float x,float y,float w,float h) {
    TMPVEC.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    camera.unproject(TMPVEC);
    return Gdx.input.justTouched() && TMPVEC.x > x && TMPVEC.x < x+w;
}
```

You can only use the iterator at the place where you're iterating. So you must acquire a local reference at the loop like this:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    for (Iterator<Sprite> iterator = enemies.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Sprite drawEnemy = iterator.next();
        drawEnemy.draw(batch);
        drawEnemy.translateY(deltaTime * movement);
        if (touched((drawEnemy.getX(),drawEnemy.getY(), drawEnemy.getWidth(),drawEnemy.getHeight())){
            iterator.remove();
            Pools.free(sprite);
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, the above is kind of muddy because you're mixing update and drawing code up together, and drawing before updating, and checking for touches over and over without need. I would redo it all like this:

```
private Vector3 TMPVEC = new Vector3();

public void update (Camera camera, float deltaTime) {
    boolean checkTouch = Gdx.input.justTouched();
    if (checkTouch) {
        TMPVEC.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(TMPVEC);
    } //This way we only unproject the point once for all sprites

    for (Iterator<Sprite> iterator = enemies.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Sprite enemy = iterator.next();
        enemy.translateY(deltaTime * movement);

        if (checkTouch && touched(enemy, TMPVEC)){
            iterator.remove();
            Pools.free(sprite);
        }
    }
}

private void touched (Sprite sprite, Vector3 touchPoint){
    return sprite.getX() <= touchPoint.x && 
        sprite.getX() + sprite.getWidth() <= touchPoint.x;
}

public void draw (SpriteBatch batch){
    for (Sprite sprite : enemies) sprite.draw(batch);
}
```

Here you would call `update` before `draw` from the owning class.